# How to exclude n\a values from the graph?

Tags: r, na, implicit

The graph I am getting for this code includes a plot for the null values too even though i excluded them and gives a warning
Warning message:
Factor `num.employees` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na`

```
#------How does size of company relate to incidence of mental health disorders?
# quick summary of number of employees breakdown
summary(mentalhealth$num.employees)

# get only respondents who have answer the question
size.company <- mentalhealth %>% filter(num.employees != "")

# order levels of factor to be in ascending order
size.company$num.employees <- factor(size.company$num.employees, levels = 
 c("1--5", "6--25", "26--100", "100--500", "500--1000", "More than 1000"))

# group by variables of interest
size.company.grouped <- size.company %>% group_by(num.employees, 
currently.have.mental.disorder)

# calculate frequencies
forPlotting <- size.company.grouped %>%
summarise(n = n()) %>%
mutate(freq = n / sum(n))

# show freqs
#forPlotting

#plot relative frequencies with a stacked bar plot filled by current 
diagnosis
gg <- ggplot(forPlotting, aes(x = num.employees, y = freq, fill = 
currently.have.mental.disorder)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
ggtitle("No relationship between company size and incidence of mental 
disorders") +
xlab("Company size (number of employees)") +
ylab("Relative frequency") +
guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL)) +
scale_fill_manual(values=wes_palette(n=3, name="GrandBudapest2")) +
theme_bw()

ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]want to exclude the null value bar from the image

Comment: Hi, you should not post code image. We can't really help you with this, please add your code in your question so we can try to help  you.

Comment: Hi, I have added the code too. Thank you.